# Trying to hook up an Alesis QS6.1 keyboard to a Mac G4, do I need to install a serial 8-pin to the Mac or is there an adapter?

Tags: mac, adapter, avisynth

I have an Alesis QS6.1 keyboard that I need to connect to a Mac G4. 
8-pin serial. 
But I do not have an 8-pin on the Mac. 
Can I get one to put in or can I use an adapter (with or without software)?

[image]

Comment: You might want to ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ which a stack exchange site specifically for apple.

Comment: It would be on topic for Ask Different, but might get better response on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ You can get [USB to mini DIN](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Compatible-FT-857-FT-857D-FT-897D/dp/B08Y5K6TNP/ref=pd_sbs_1/257-5098030-6535411?pd_rd_w=p3EUR&pf_rd_p=b3232d54-1e37-435b-b370-81046eef630a&pf_rd_r=44X2CB83P8Q42J0CA9CA&pd_rd_r=c3b82258-8647-4e24-91a0-86fb743e3496&pd_rd_wg=qPLT1&pd_rd_i=B08Y5K6TNP&psc=1) but I've no idea if that would make it functional. You will very probably need drivers/software for that particular Mac OS for it to be recognised.